# How to append some text to an array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have an string with array output

`["ant","bird","cat","dog","elephant"]`

Now my question is I want to add @xyz.com

Output has to look like

`["ant@xyz.com","bird@xyz.com","cat@xyz.com","dog@xyz.com","elephant@xyz.com"]`

Could anyone please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the question says C#, the label says javascript; the text could be either

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
using System.Linq

var arr = ["ant","bird","cat","dog","elephant"];
var output = arr.Select(s => s + "@xyz.com")
```

Comment: Instead of var can we do it in a string for var it is working fine.

Comment: `var ntlogins = NT_Login.Select(s => s + "@xyz.com");
string emailids = (ntlogins.Length > 0) ? string.Join(", ", ntlogins) : ""; `